# endeca returning zero results in refinements when none of refinements available in ref app?

Tags: endeca, refinements, endeca-workbench

I am using Endeca 3.1.2 Assembler API. When I am hitting the Endeca query, its giving me some bunch of refinements which contains zero counts and some positive counts .

Example:

```
category 
    **category1(0)**
      category2(25)
      **category3(0)**
```

Like this result I am getting.  When I am hitting the same query in jspref application I am not getting any refinements which contains zero count.

My expectation is that I don't want to get that zero count refinements on the available refinements.

Please help me to get out from this.

Answer (score 0):

You might have [disabled refinements](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29584_01/webhelp/mdex_basicDev/src/cbdv_urlparams_disabled_refinements.html) enabled in your query.

1. Check whether you have the [Ndr](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29584_01/webhelp/mdex_basicDev/src/rbdv_urlparams_ndr.html) parameter in Dgraph request log file
2. If so, ensure your code doesn't have: `ENEQuery.setNavDisabledRefinementsConfig()` method.

Comment: Thanks for your response.. i have not create any custom ene query classes in my application. and i used to put this Ndr parameter in removeAlways property in NavigationStateBuilder even it is not working.. also i could not find any Ndr parameter in D graph request log file.. Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post both Dgraph reqlog lines when you hit with the application and with the jspref?

Comment: 1452077011139 192.168.1.4 - 1384 76331 10.18 2.10 200 46019 0 2 /graph?node=0&refinement=dimvalid:100972+dynrank:0+exposed:1&groupby=material.repositoryId&offset=0&nbins=10&allbins=2&autophrase=1&autophrasedwim=1&irversion=640 - Accept%3A+%2A%2F%2A%0D%0AUser%2DAgent%3A+Java%2F1%2E6%2E0%5F43%0D%0AHost%3A+192%2E168%2E1%2E119%3A16002%0D%0AConnection%3A+keep%2Dalive%0D%0A

Comment: Ntk=AFFY_MATERIAL&enePort=16002&Ne=100972&eneHost=localhost&Nu=material.repositoryId&N=0&Np=1&Ntx=mode+matchallpartial

Answer (score -1):

Endeca has one of the features called implicit dimensions. There might be the case that implicit dimension is being displayed to the front-end. Endeca provides implicit dimension as part of the query response.
Following code is being used to get implicit dimension.

Navigation.getCompleteDimensions().getDimension(dimensionid)